# How to filter last 8 hours of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to get the last 8 hrs of data from a dataframe. Is there any way to achieve this?

Suppose I have a dataframe with timestamp:

```
Time                  X      Y
19/8/2017 10:00:00  824.93  6.42
19/8/2017 10:20:00  825.88  6.41
19/8/2017 10:40:00  825.59  6.45
19/8/2017 11:00:00  826.18  6.6
19/8/2017 11:20:00  825.2   6.62
19/8/2017 11:40:00  825.3   6.65
19/8/2017 12:00:00  824.72  6.54
19/8/2017 12:20:00  825.72  6.45
19/8/2017 12:40:00  824.99  6.35
19/8/2017 13:00:00  824.63  6.31
19/8/2017 13:20:00  825.87  6.34
19/8/2017 13:40:00  826.12  6.29
19/8/2017 14:00:00  825.41  6.31
19/8/2017 14:20:00  825.34  6.36
19/8/2017 14:40:00  825.15  6.39
19/8/2017 15:00:00  824.87  6.15
19/8/2017 15:20:00  825.57  6.17
19/8/2017 15:40:00  825.35  6.2
19/8/2017 16:00:00  824.94  6.26
19/8/2017 16:20:00  825.86  6.39
19/8/2017 16:40:00  824.74  6.39
19/8/2017 17:00:00  823.46  6.33
19/8/2017 17:20:00  824.46  6.41
19/8/2017 17:40:00  824.67  6.4
19/8/2017 18:00:00  824.38  6.36
19/8/2017 18:20:00  825.23  6.37
19/8/2017 18:40:00  826.09  6.37
19/8/2017 19:00:00  824.77  6.32
19/8/2017 19:20:00  824.18  6.34
19/8/2017 19:40:00  823.82  6.33
19/8/2017 20:00:00  825 6.39
19/8/2017 20:20:00  825.01  6.4
19/8/2017 20:40:00  824.24  6.45
19/8/2017 21:00:00  817.65  6.17
19/8/2017 21:20:00  781.58  4.92
19/8/2017 21:40:00  739.89  3.51
```

I want to extract last 8 hours of data from this dataframe.

I tried this but nothing i can do:

```
last8 = (df["Time"] == (dfs["Time"].shift() + Timedelta(hours = 8))).cumsum()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean last 8 hours from the max time, or current time?

Comment: @Zero, 8 hours from the last time of the dataframe i.e. 19/8/2017 21:40:00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get last 8 hours from the max time *(last time in this case)*

```
In [2178]: df[df['Time'] > df['Time'].max() - pd.Timedelta(hours=8)]
Out[2178]:
                  Time       X     Y
12 2017-08-19 14:00:00  825.41  6.31
13 2017-08-19 14:20:00  825.34  6.36
14 2017-08-19 14:40:00  825.15  6.39
15 2017-08-19 15:00:00  824.87  6.15
16 2017-08-19 15:20:00  825.57  6.17
17 2017-08-19 15:40:00  825.35  6.20
18 2017-08-19 16:00:00  824.94  6.26
19 2017-08-19 16:20:00  825.86  6.39
20 2017-08-19 16:40:00  824.74  6.39
21 2017-08-19 17:00:00  823.46  6.33
22 2017-08-19 17:20:00  824.46  6.41
23 2017-08-19 17:40:00  824.67  6.40
24 2017-08-19 18:00:00  824.38  6.36
25 2017-08-19 18:20:00  825.23  6.37
26 2017-08-19 18:40:00  826.09  6.37
27 2017-08-19 19:00:00  824.77  6.32
28 2017-08-19 19:20:00  824.18  6.34
29 2017-08-19 19:40:00  823.82  6.33
30 2017-08-19 20:00:00  825.00  6.39
31 2017-08-19 20:20:00  825.01  6.40
32 2017-08-19 20:40:00  824.24  6.45
33 2017-08-19 21:00:00  817.65  6.17
34 2017-08-19 21:20:00  781.58  4.92
35 2017-08-19 21:40:00  739.89  3.51
```

Comment: And, @MaxU suggested quite useful shorthand `pd.Timedelta('8H')` alternative to `pd.Timedelta(hours=8)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[df.Time >= pd.datetime.now() - pd.Timedelta('8H')]
```