# Filter Dataframe by Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have the following dataframe df:

```
TimeStamp

2021-03-21 09:16:33
2021-03-21 09:17:06
2021-03-21 09:19:19
2021-04-13 12:20:32
2021-04-13 12:20:39
```

I want to filter the dataframe to only obtain the transactions from the past 36 hours; I tried the following code but I have always found dealing with timestamps troublesome.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel(input_path)
now = datetime.now()
temp = df[now-df['TimeStamp'].astype('timedelta64[h]').iloc[-1] >= 24]
```

Therefore the end result is:

```
TimeStamp

2021-04-13 12:20:32
2021-04-13 12:20:39
```

Thank you

Comment: Try using pd.Timedelta(hours=36)].  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343011/how-to-filter-last-8-hours-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `TimeStamp` is converted `to_datetime()` and then use `pd.Timedelta(hours=36)`:

```py
df.TimeStamp = pd.to_datetime(TimeStamp)
df[df.TimeStamp > (now - pd.Timedelta(hours=36))]
```

Alternatively you can load the excel with `parse_dates` so you don't have to manually convert to datetime: `df = pd.read_excel(input_path, parse_dates=['TimeStamp'])`